# Research in the Discrete Logarithm Problem

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, research, reference-works, discrete-logarithms

I have already taken a course on Abstract algebra and tis implementation in the criprography,  among other topics the course focused on the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm)  in finite fields.
Now, I would like to deepen this topic, especially in the algorithms to solve it. (See [Discrete logarithm records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records))

I would like to find a paper or works that not only explains the theoretical aspect of the DLP, but also the current state of research in this field.
For example:  What are the latest advances on algorithm optimization? What possibilities provide the quantum computation ? Is there a research network that focuses on this field?

Any recommendations, books, paper or Link  may be helpful, Thanks!

Comment: http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/discretelogs2014.pdf